# is there a way to convert .html file (tab delimited text file) to csv without using pandas

Tags: python-3.x

I have a .html file but the file does not contain any tags. I want to convert this .html file to either excel or CSV. So that I can use pandas for carrying some operations.

Currently, I am unable to use pandas as it searches for a table, tr tag for converting HTML file to CSV or excel.

An example HTML file (full page available [here](http://vint.0x01.ru/~vint/raid_test/5/localhost-0.html)):

```
<title>Vdbench output/localhost-0.html</title><pre>
Slave summary report for slave=localhost-0

Console log:                     <A HREF="localhost-0.stdout.html">Slave stdout/stderr</A>

Link to Run Definitions:         <A HREF="#_1313953385">run1 For loops: xfersize=4k</A>
                                                 <A HREF="#_399573350">xfersize=16k</A>
                                                 <A HREF="#_463345942">xfersize=32k</A>
                                                 <A HREF="#_195600860">xfersize=64k</A>
                                                 <A HREF="#_1334729950">xfersize=128k</A>


<a name="_1313953385"></a><i><b>19:28:33.002 Starting RD=run1; I/O rate: Uncontrolled MAX; elapsed=7200 warmup=600; For loops: xfersize=4k</b></i>


Mar 10, 2018  interval        i/o   MB/sec   bytes   read     resp     read    write     resp     resp queue  cpu%  cpu%
                             rate  1024**2     i/o    pct     time     resp     resp      max   stddev depth sys+u   sys
19:29:33.086         1   22213.93    86.77    4096  50.00    0.353    0.229    0.478   21.536    0.304   7.9   1.8   1.1
19:30:33.045         2   23145.18    90.41    4096  50.04    0.342    0.227    0.456   21.646    0.278   7.9   1.8   1.2
19:31:33.045         3   23540.93    91.96    4096  50.09    0.336    0.225    0.448   21.278    0.274   7.9   1.8   1.1
19:32:33.044         4   23456.57    91.63    4096  49.99    0.337    0.226    0.449   21.621    0.276   7.9   1.9   1.2
19:33:33.045         5   22726.32    88.77    4096  50.02    0.348    0.230    0.466   22.555    0.283   7.9   2.0   1.3
19:34:33.045         6   22475.53    87.80    4096  50.01    0.352    0.229    0.475   26.673    0.287   7.9   2.1   1.4
19:35:33.044         7   22852.70    89.27    4096  50.01    0.346    0.226    0.466   21.195    0.277   7.9   2.2   1.4
19:36:33.044         8   22929.10    89.57    4096  49.98    0.345    0.229    0.460   21.640    0.277   7.9   2.2   1.5
19:37:33.043         9   22884.20    89.39    4096  50.06    0.346    0.228    0.463   24.478    0.288   7.9   2.0   1.3
19:38:33.045        10   22891.77    89.42    4096  50.00    0.345    0.228    0.463   21.435    0.280   7.9   2.1   1.3
19:39:33.043        11   22358.80    87.34    4096  50.00    0.354    0.228    0.479   21.616    0.282   7.9   1.9   1.2
19:40:33.044        12   22611.53    88.33    4096  49.97    0.350    0.228    0.472   22.261    0.281   7.9   2.1   1.3
19:41:33.046        13   22450.95    87.70    4096  50.05    0.352    0.226    0.478   21.789    0.284   7.9   2.4   1.5
19:42:33.043        14   22610.82    88.32    4096  50.08    0.350    0.227    0.473   21.576    0.282   7.9   2.5   1.4
19:43:33.046        15   22271.13    87.00    4096  50.01    0.355    0.228    0.482   21.216    0.285   7.9   1.9   1.2
19:44:33.044        16   22264.43    86.97    4096  49.99    0.355    0.228    0.482   21.643    0.283   7.9   1.9   1.2
19:45:33.043        17   22710.52    88.71    4096  49.99    0.349    0.223    0.475   21.742    0.284   7.9   1.8   1.2
19:46:33.043        18   22806.60    89.09    4096  49.97    0.347    0.225    0.469   21.536    0.278   7.9   2.0   1.3
19:47:33.043        19   22353.10    87.32    4096  50.01    0.354    0.232    0.476   21.104    0.277   7.9   2.0   1.3
19:48:33.043        20   22285.80    87.05    4096  49.99    0.355    0.230    0.481   21.626    0.282   7.9   1.9   1.2
19:49:33.043        21   22611.10    88.32    4096  50.02    0.350    0.227    0.474   21.776    0.281   7.9   1.9   1.2
19:50:33.044        22   22283.10    87.04    4096  50.07    0.355    0.230    0.481   20.364    0.284   7.9   1.9   1.2
19:51:33.043        23   22308.05    87.14    4096  50.00    0.355    0.228    0.482   21.341    0.282   7.9   2.0   1.3
19:52:33.043        24   22244.08    86.89    4096  50.01    0.356    0.230    0.482   21.464    0.276   7.9   2.0   1.3
19:53:33.042        25   22502.08    87.90    4096  50.05    0.352    0.227    0.477   21.740    0.283   7.9   2.0   1.3
19:54:33.042        26   22170.22    86.60    4096  50.04    0.357    0.229    0.486   26.998    0.291   7.9   1.9   1.2
19:55:33.043        27   22216.00    86.78    4096  50.02    0.356    0.230    0.484   21.016    0.290   7.9   2.0   1.3
19:56:33.043        28   21692.47    84.74    4096  50.04    0.365    0.231    0.498   22.148    0.286   7.9   2.0   1.3
19:57:33.043        29   22002.18    85.95    4096  50.02    0.359    0.229    0.490   21.995    0.285   7.9   2.2   1.4
19:58:33.044        30   22139.08    86.48    4096  50.03    0.357    0.228    0.487   22.367    0.283   7.9   2.2   1.3

Mar 10, 2018  interval        i/o   MB/sec   bytes   read     resp     read    write     resp     resp queue  cpu%  cpu%
                             rate  1024**2     i/o    pct     time     resp     resp      max   stddev depth sys+u   sys
19:59:33.043        31   21665.45    84.63    4096  49.99    0.365    0.229    0.502   21.849    0.290   7.9   2.0   1.3
20:00:33.042        32   22208.17    86.75    4096  50.08    0.356    0.229    0.484   21.479    0.288   7.9   2.1   1.3
20:01:33.043        33   22254.08    86.93    4096  49.90    0.356    0.229    0.482   21.963    0.287   7.9   2.0   1.3
20:02:33.042        34   21757.10    84.99    4096  49.99    0.364    0.229    0.499   21.713    0.288   7.9   2.1   1.3
20:03:33.043        35   21884.17    85.49    4096  49.99    0.362    0.229    0.494   21.974    0.286   7.9   2.0   1.3
20:04:33.042        36   21920.02    85.63    4096  50.06    0.361    0.229    0.494   22.162    0.285   7.9   1.9   1.2
20:05:33.042        37   21375.17    83.50    4096  49.97    0.370    0.229    0.511   21.662    0.291   7.9   2.0   1.3
20:06:33.043        38   21563.78    84.23    4096  49.97    0.367    0.231    0.503   21.654    0.292   7.9   2.1   1.3
20:07:33.043        39   21792.60    85.13    4096  50.03    0.363    0.229    0.498   24.398    0.301   7.9   2.1   1.3
20:08:33.043        40   21515.17    84.04    4096  50.02    0.368    0.232    0.504   21.738    0.290   7.9   2.0   1.3
20:09:33.043        41   21761.85    85.01    4096  50.07    0.364    0.232    0.496   20.902    0.285   7.9   2.2   1.4
20:10:33.044        42   21676.10    84.67    4096  49.98    0.365    0.230    0.501   22.007    0.289   7.9   2.0   1.3
20:11:33.043        43   22036.17    86.08    4096  50.03    0.359    0.231    0.487   21.992    0.286   7.9   2.0   1.3
20:12:33.043        44   21638.15    84.52    4096  49.94    0.366    0.233    0.498   21.510    0.293   7.9   2.0   1.3
20:13:33.042        45   21951.72    85.75    4096  50.07    0.361    0.231    0.491   21.774    0.286   7.9   2.0   1.3
20:14:33.042        46   21327.32    83.31    4096  50.07    0.371    0.232    0.511   21.522    0.295   7.9   2.1   1.3
20:15:33.043        47   21736.30    84.91    4096  49.99    0.364    0.232    0.496   32.060    0.294   7.9   2.2   1.4
20:16:33.043        48   21526.45    84.09    4096  50.02    0.368    0.231    0.504   21.944    0.286   7.9   2.2   1.4
20:17:33.044        49   21509.20    84.02    4096  49.95    0.368    0.231    0.505   21.529    0.287   7.9   2.1   1.3
20:18:33.043        50   21079.62    82.34    4096  49.99    0.376    0.232    0.520   21.797    0.296   7.9   2.1   1.3
20:19:33.042        51   21683.97    84.70    4096  50.02    0.365    0.235    0.495   21.841    0.291   7.9   2.1   1.3
20:20:33.042        52   21517.90    84.05    4096  49.95    0.368    0.233    0.502   21.721    0.291   7.9   2.1   1.3
20:21:33.045        53   21582.05    84.30    4096  49.95    0.367    0.230    0.503   21.508    0.288   7.9   2.0   1.3
20:22:33.043        54   21693.77    84.74    4096  49.90    0.365    0.233    0.496   22.114    0.283   7.9   2.2   1.4
20:23:33.044        55   21809.38    85.19    4096  50.03    0.363    0.232    0.494   21.552    0.283   7.9   2.1   1.3
20:24:33.043        56   21323.70    83.30    4096  49.98    0.371    0.232    0.511   35.232    0.298   7.9   2.0   1.3
20:25:33.044        57   21538.38    84.13    4096  50.03    0.367    0.232    0.503   21.807    0.292   7.9   2.2   1.4
20:26:33.043        58   21482.22    83.91    4096  49.95    0.368    0.233    0.504   21.613    0.291   7.9   2.2   1.4
20:27:33.043        59   21915.38    85.61    4096  50.00    0.361    0.230    0.492   22.282    0.285   7.9   2.1   1.4
20:28:33.042        60   21716.03    84.83    4096  49.93    0.365    0.232    0.497   21.166    0.285   7.9   2.0   1.3
```

Can anyone let me know how can i convert this file.

Comment: What's the structure of that HTML File? How are rows and columns represented if there is no table? Give an example of that HTML file.

Comment: I have attached a link for the sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these files are consistent and they have the same structure, what you can do is to read the HTML file as a regular file in Python, strip away this part:

```
Slave summary report for slave=localhost-0

Console log:                     Slave stdout/stderr

Link to Run Definitions:         run1 For loops: xfersize=4k
                                                 xfersize=16k
                                                 xfersize=32k
                                                 xfersize=64k
                                                 xfersize=128k


19:28:33.002 Starting RD=run1; I/O rate: Uncontrolled MAX; elapsed=7200 warmup=600; For loops: xfersize=4k
```

And then use the remaining as a text file that you can then parse to Pandas as it really is just a structural text file.

Something like this might help you get started:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

with open('test.html') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    body = content[14:] # Skip header
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(body)), delim_whitespace=True)
    print(df)
```

Comment: Format of the file remains .html and even i tried with .txt file but problem is columns are not read properly and it  shows only one column but treats the whole data

Comment: Mar 18, 2020    interval        i/o   MB/sec   bytes   read     resp     read    write     read    write     resp  queue  cpu%  rate  102             
1    20:38:54.038           1      824.0     3.22  ...                                                                                   
319  20:43:53.009   avg_2-300     2621.3    10.24  ...                                                                                 

[320 rows x 1 columns]

Comment: Thank u it helped me

Comment: Glad to her this. Please consider accepting the answer as accepted by clicking the “tick” button next to the answer you find useful.

Comment: I am new to this. Thanks for helping. I need one more help. "body = content[14:] " in the above-highlighted thing the starting 14 lines are skipped. but this number of lines varies from file to file. it may be 13,12 ... and even the date column varies.... so how can I skip the lines based on some condition that is applicable to all files in common.

Comment: Can you please help me... I have commented my question in the previous comment

Answer (score 0):

vdbench has this as a built in. /vdbench parseflat -i flatfile.html -o something.csv .  Look in the pdf.

jim